# query on sql MySQL 5.1 - find phone numbers with specific area code

Tags: sql, mysql

In a sql based query, I need to check that the persons I select from data should have a cell phone with area code 256. How do we check this? I have cell phone numbers as BIGINT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried simple soln like

**mysql:

    `select * from table where cellno like '256%'`**

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean MySql 5.1.

In any case,

```
Select * from persons where persons.cellphonenumber % 10000000 == 256
```

Or something similar with the modulus operator.

Comment: How do we use Like function in this case?

Comment: It seems in any case such a solution would be messy since you're storing everything in a single column. In the ideal case, you could store the area code in a separate column. Given that, it seems that % is the best way to get at the 3 front digits while not converting to another data type (which would be equally messy).

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
select if(substr( convert(<your cell phone field>, char(20)), 1,3) = '256', 1, 0)


select if(substr( convert(25746744073709551615, char(20)), 1,3) = '256', 1, 0)
```

or you could use like:

```
select if(convert(25646744073709551615, char(20)) like '256%', 1, 0)
```